# 'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,0) into shape (1,1)' when using sm.tsa.SARIMAX

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I am trying to use the statsmodels.api.tsa.SARIMAX function to model some 30 minute frequency time series data but am getting the error below.

The SARIMAX function is not included in the latest released version of statsmodels, so I have downloaded and installed the dev version from http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/binaries/statsmodels-0.7.0-2670ed0.win-amd64-py3.4.exe against a 3.4 environment of python created with conda.

Everything is running in a Jupyter notebook, my data looks like so:

```
print(binned_vals.head(15))

2016-01-07 09:00:00     21394
2016-01-07 09:30:00    236515
2016-01-07 10:00:00    161676
2016-01-07 10:30:00    223484
2016-01-07 11:00:00    167918
2016-01-07 11:30:00    198435
2016-01-07 12:00:00     99343
2016-01-07 12:30:00    150210
2016-01-07 13:00:00    254153
2016-01-07 13:30:00    258123
2016-01-07 14:00:00     97485
2016-01-07 14:30:00         0
2016-01-07 15:00:00         0
2016-01-07 15:30:00         0
2016-01-07 16:00:00         0
Freq: 30T, Name: value, dtype: int64
```

And the error is:

```
fit1 = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(binned_vals, order=(0,1,0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f42d87d7881a> in <module>()
      1 # fit1 = model(binned_vals, (0,1,0), (0,0,0,0))
----> 2 fit1 = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(binned_vals, order=(0,1,0))

C:\Users\Gus\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, order, seasonal_order, trend, measurement_error, time_varying_regression, mle_regression, simple_differencing, enforce_stationarity, enforce_invertibility, hamilton_representation, **kwargs)
    517         self.ssm.design = self.initial_design
    518         self.ssm.state_intercept = self.initial_state_intercept
--> 519         self.ssm.transition = self.initial_transition
    520         self.ssm.selection = self.initial_selection
    521 

C:\Users\Gus\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py in initial_transition(self)
    776 
    777         # T_c
--> 778         transition[start:end, start:end] = companion_matrix(self._k_order)
    779         if self.hamilton_representation:
    780             transition[start:end, start:end] = np.transpose(

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,0) into shape (1,1)
```

I have trawled google for related errors but there is not much info (probably because this is a dev function!).

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: order=(0,1,0) for ARIMA has nothing to estimate because there are no ARMA parameters, just differencing, i.e. it's just a random walk. So, I guess that's not supported. What's the use case for this?

Comment: I was trying to iteratively figure out the ARMA parameters by first differencing, then analysing the auto-correlation/partial auto-correlation plots.  Was intending on then building up the ARMA terms after I had stabilised the series - is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can just difference the series with pandas and then plot acf and pacf. Then, start with a model that has at least one AR or MA parameter. You could also open an issue with statsmodels to see whether this can be included as a null benchmark. I'm not sure it's possible, but ARMA(X) recently got OLS as a special case when there are no lags to make it easier to compare different specifications.

Comment: Ah, I missed the [diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) function, thank you very much!  The functionality seems okay to me, do you think it would be worth raising a bug to make the error text more useful?